# Auto updating for file content similar to tail -f

Tags: buffers

Is it possible to setup vim for auto updating on changing of file content?

I think about working with logs that can extend if new event happened.
What I expect is that vim will spot a file change and update the buffer.

To avoid "merge conflicts" I can run in read-only mode and just
use vim as a perfect viewer with all search capability and well
known user interface

Comment: You can `set autoread` but it’s bot quite the same

Comment: If there is no auto-scrolling it is even better for me.
I can always go to new portion of data with 'G'

Answer (score 3):

Tracking file change automatically is OS-dependent, so by default Vim only checks file timestamps (`:checktime`) on focus gain (works in GUI) and after executing shell commands. But you can force it any moment using a bit of scripting.

For example, check by timer:

```
function! PollBuffer(bufnr, msec)
    " make sure autoread is on, so Vim won't ask any questions
    call setbufvar(a:bufnr, '&autoread', 1)
    " check timestamp by timer event
    return timer_start(a:msec, {_ -> execute(a:bufnr..'checktime')}, {'repeat': -1})
endfunction

let timerID = PollBuffer(bufnr('foobar.txt'), 5000)
```

Comment: I use vim on Ubuntu or WSL Ubuntu in BASH console

In this function is fixed foobar.txt filename. Is there any variable/pointer to currently opened file that I can put in this place?

Comment: @AdamMierzwiak for example, `expand('%')`.

Comment: @AdamMierzwiak Simply `bufnr()` without argument